# Display Nested Mongoose data on EJS template?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to display order data from a nested mongoose object and I can't seem to get the data to display correctly. Appreciate all help in advance.

Here is the order model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new Schema({
  //todo: check the user part in this model
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    cart: {type: Object, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    paymentId: {type: String, required: true},
    email:{type: String, required: true},
    time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', schema);
```

Here is how the data is saved to the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5975214fc8db300731d0e8b8"), "user" : ObjectId("5951d4d1f57b440556898e1a"), "cart" : { "items" : { "596068
4581c02d077c914283" : { "item" : { "_id" : "5960684581c02d077c914283", "imagePath" : "https://www.swarovski.com/is-bin/inters
hop.static/WFS/SCO-Media-Site/-/-/publicimages//CG/B2C/PROD/180/Swarovski-Cosmic-Bracelet-5226308-W180.jpg", "title" : "Brace
let 1", "description" : "This is the first Bracelet in the collection.", "price" : 10, "__v" : 0 }, "qty" : 1, "price" : 10 }
, "59742cad8f1bf6071b5419cb" : { "item" : { "_id" : "59742cad8f1bf6071b5419cb", "title" : "Bracelet 2 ", "imagePath" : "https
://img0.etsystatic.com/160/0/12655872/il_340x270.1187191078_i2ha.jpg", "description" : "This is the second Bracelet in the co
llection.", "price" : 5, "__v" : 0 }, "qty" : 1, "price" : 5 }, "59742ebdd1242f07530d2b30" : { "item" : { "_id" : "59742ebdd1
242f07530d2b30", "title" : "Bracelet 3", "imagePath" : "https://www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/category-
tiles/pearl-bracelets.jpg", "description" : "This is the third Bracelet in the collection.", "price" : 12, "__v" : 0 }, "qty"
 : 1, "price" : 12 } }, "totalQty" : 3, "totalPrice" : 27 }, "address" : "6210 place", "name" : "pauls", "paymentId" : "ch_1A
isRfDfJryYeuMpbJGWY2NV", "email" : "pauls@a.com", "time" : ISODate("2017-07-23T22:21:03.819Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

I would like to display the data in a table using ejs:

```
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
    <% orders.forEach(function(order){ %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=...item%> </td>
    <td><%=...description%> </td>
    <td><%=...price%> </td>
    <td><%=...quantity%> </td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
    </table>
```

Here is the route:

```
router.get('/order', function(req, res){
  Order.find({}, function(err, allOrders){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      } else {
         res.render("admin/order", {orders: allOrders});
      }
  });
});
```

Here is the cart:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.items = oldCart.items || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

    this.add = function (item, id) {
        var storedItem = this.items[id];
        if (!storedItem) {
            storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
        }
        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;

    };

    this.reduceByOne = function (id) {
        this.items[id].qty--;
        this.items[id].price -= this.items[id].item.price;
        this.totalQty--;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;

        if (this.items[id].qty <=0) {
            delete this.items[id];
        }
    };

    this.removeItem = function (id) {
        this.totalQty -= this.items[id].qty;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].price;
        delete this.items[id];
    };

    this.generateArray = function () {
        var arr = [];
        for (var id in this.items) {
            arr.push(this.items[id]);
        }
        return arr;
    };
};
```

Edit: Now data is saved like below:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6b11306910658b1ff57"), "address" : "6210 place", "name" : "frank", "paymentId" : "ch_1AjJRVDfJ
ryYeuMpJC80cp5k", "email" : "g@mail.com", "time" : ISODate("2017-07-25T03:10:41.522Z"), "cart" : [ { "items" : { "59752
28a215c0f074b64f58e" : { "item" : { "_id" : "5975228a215c0f074b64f58e", "title" : "Bracelet 3", "imagePath" : "https://
www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/category-tiles/pearl-bracelets.jpg", "description" : "This is brace
let 3", "price" : 12, "__v" : 0 }, "qty" : 1, "price" : 12 }, "59752242215c0f074b64f58c" : { "item" : { "_id" : "597522
42215c0f074b64f58c", "title" : "Bracelet 1", "imagePath" : "https://img0.etsystatic.com/160/0/12655872/il_340x270.11871
91078_i2ha.jpg", "description" : "This is bracelet 1", "price" : 10, "__v" : 0 }, "qty" : 2, "price" : 20 }, "5975226a2
15c0f074b64f58d" : { "item" : { "_id" : "5975226a215c0f074b64f58d", "title" : "Bracelet 2", "imagePath" : "http://media
.tiffany.com/is/image/Tiffany/EcomBrowseM/paloma-picasso-knot-bead-bracelet-34946183_963148_ED.jpg?op_usm=1.00,1.00,6.0
0&defaultImage=NoImageAvailable&&", "description" : "This is bracelet 2", "price" : 5, "__v" : 0 }, "qty" : 1, "price"
: 5 } }, "totalQty" : 4, "totalPrice" : 37 } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: This `cart: {type: Object, required: true}` is an error. This should not be `Object` but in fact you likely meant to be an "array". You somehow managed to coerce something that "should" be an array into an object of "named keys". But moreover, since you used `Object` the actual data is persisted as a "string" and is not in fact an `Object` at all. At "worst" you meant `Mixed` which does something different. But it really "should be" an array instead.

Comment: I changed it to an Array type and now data is saved as shown above in the Edit I added. I also added the cart for reference above. I still cant seem to get to specific data lets say the title for example. I can get as far as this <%= console.log(order.cart[0].items) %> in ejs to show me the items but can't get deeper, what would I need to add to get to the title level ? Really appreciate your help.